# Hermes not enabled in Android native project

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, eas

I have react native (expo) app, when I try to run expo publish command I get *JavaScript engine configuration is inconsistent between app.json and Android native project(android/gradle.properties  and  app/build.gradle). In app.json: Hermes is enabled. In Android native project: Hermes is not enabled*. But these native files have hermes enabled - hermesEnabled=true (in gradle.properties) and in app/build.gradle:

```
if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
   implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
   }
```

I've checked react native documentation and couldn't find any other way to enable hermes, has anyone had the same issue? Am I missing something? Any advise is greatly appreciated